# kafka - message with partition key put into wrong partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I would like to know, under which situation does messages with same partition key go into different partition.

I had run two consumers belonging to the same group listening on a topic in console using the command given below:

```
sudo /etc/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --
bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic demo3  --consumer.config 
config/consumer.properties --property print.key=true --property 
key.separator=:
```

I used "nmred/kafka-php" library to put messages to the topic `demo3` with key `abc`. When i send multiple such messages, i found that few of the messages goes to the second consumer whereas most of the messages goes to consumer 1.

As i used the same key `abc` for all messages, i expected all the messages to be consumed by the same consumer. Each consumer is binded to each partition.

I use the following code to produce messages:

```
$config = \Kafka\ProducerConfig::getInstance();
$config->setMetadataRefreshIntervalMs(10000);
$config->setMetadataBrokerList('x.x.x.x:9092', 'y.y.y.y:9092');

$config->setRequiredAck(1);
$config->setIsAsyn(false);
$config->setProduceInterval(500);
$producer = new \Kafka\Producer(
function() {
    return [
        [
            'topic' => 'demo3',
            'value' => 'test message.',
            'key' => 'abc',
        ],
    ];
}
);

$producer->success(function($result) {
 var_dump($result);
});
$producer->error(function($errorCode) {
    var_dump($errorCode);
});
$producer->send(true);
```

[image]

This screenshot clearly shows that 3 messages had been sent to one consumer and the other one to another consumer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are saying is true, you should see messages with same key "abc" being consumed by the same consumer.
Can you check if a rebalancing starts and maybe the first consumer left partition to the other ?
Or, using this php kafka producer (I have never used it) can you trace in which partition each message is put. A kafka producer should get the RecordMetadata information when sending a message in order to know at which partition and offset the message is assigned. Because it's the producer to decide the destination partition, you should be sure the the php kafka producer is working fine.

Comment: there had been no re balancing during the period in which i had send those messages

Comment: then you need to get some log from the Kafka PHP producer and how it processes the destination partition from the key and if it's always the same based on the same key.

Comment: The problem seems to be at the client itself. I tried with java client, it worked as expected with the default partitioning algo. The issue is related to the partitioning algo in the php library.

Comment: If it wasn't a possible re-balancing happening that it had to be the PHP client for sure ;)

Comment: You should check the PHP Kafka client source code, maybe it doesn't support keyed message but it's just using a round robin. What is the client you are using?

Comment: i had checked the code, surprisingly it was randomly selecting a partition!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Java docs](http://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html),

> If a valid partition number is specified, that partition will be used
> when sending the record.
>
> If no partition is specified but a key is
> present a partition will be chosen using a hash of the key.
>
> If neither key nor partition is present a partition will be assigned in a
> round-robin fashion

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am using a partition key and for the messages which i had send, i used the same partition key ("abc"), shouldn't this result in same hash and hence the same partition?

Comment: You need to have a look at the implementation of the php Producer and see whether the key is sent correctly.

Comment: As i am printing the key in the consumer console, its clear that the key has been passed correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that your consumer does not consume messages from multiple partitions?

Comment: i have two partitions. As per the o/p of the following command: sudo bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe --group demo-group --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 i can see that each consumer is binded to one partition.

Comment: You need to post some code so that we can look into it.